# unrecognized eSata

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I'm on Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit.

I have a NAS at home that uses `eSata`, since 11.10 my `eSata` is not recognized anymore.
I think I read all the post concerning the `eSata` mount in Ubuntu but with no luck.

`fdsisk -l` doesnt show me the device.

Neither is :

```
sudo rescan-scsi-bus
```

When I connect the eSata device I get this in `dmesg`

```
[37338.784750] ata8: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[37338.791065] ata8.00: ATA-8: SAMSUNG HD204UI, 1AQ10001, max UDMA/133
[37338.791071] ata8.00: 3907029168 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
[37338.797442] ata8.00: configured for UDMA/133
[37338.812801] ata8: EH complete
[37338.812930] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      SAMSUNG
HD204UI  1AQ1 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[37338.813237] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg8 type 0
[37338.813324] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdh] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks:
(2.00 TB/1.81 TiB)
[37338.813569] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdh] Write Protect is off
[37338.813575] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdh] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[37338.813768] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdh] Write cache: enabled, read cache:
enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[37338.819515]  sdh: sdh1
[37338.820525] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdh] Attached SCSI disk
```

I dont want to do a `mkfs` cause I need to keep the data on my NAS

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

So I found the solution
I tried to mount `/dev/sdh1` by adding it to `/etc/fstab`, and I saw that the NTFS partition was corrupted
I tried to fix with `ntfsfix` and `ntfs-3g` with no luck

So I connected the drive to another computer on Windows and ran a `chkdsk /f`